# How to accept indefinite inputs on a singular scanf() line in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to get an indefinite input of numbers (max 50) to create a program that does the following:

```
INPUT:
Enter Numbers: 20 15 5 8 16 12
^D

OUTPUT:
20 | ********************
15 | **********
 5 | *****
 8 | ********
 etc...
```

I am having trouble getting user input in the way specified. This is my current code, which requires the user hit enter in the terminal between each input value. I'm not looking for a solution to the entire problem, just how I can get input as shown above. The '^D' is supposed to specify when the user is done. I haven't implented it in my code as I'm confused as to how.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int
main (){

printf("Enter numbers: ");
for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_SIZE; i++)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: On another note, the loop `for(int i = 0; i <= MAX_SIZE; i++)` will iterate **51** times, not 50.

Comment: Use `fgets()`, and then `strtok()` to fill an array of converted integer values (`atoi()`)

Comment: Andre King, Why does 15 print 10 stars, yet others print `n` stars? Typo?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah yes! thank you for noting that. I realise the error now.

Comment: @SupportUkraine that makes sense, thank you! I was quite confused

Answer (score 4):

Here is something to get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int main(void)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int n=0;
    
    while(n < MAX_SIZE) {
        int a;
 
        if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1) break;
 
        arr[n++]=a; 
    }
    
    // The table is not implemented
    puts("");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Minor: Perhaps `"%-2d | "` for OP's next step?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The last printout was only to demonstrate that it works. I put no effort into it. That's up to OP to solve.

Comment: This is very helpful. I think I just didn't understand how scanf() worked properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that achieve the desired result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int array[MAX_SIZE];
    int used_indexes = 0;
    char ch = '*';

    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        int value;
        if (scanf_s("%d", &value) <= 0)
            break;
        array[i] = value;
        used_indexes++;
    }

    printf("\n\nResult:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < used_indexes; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d | ", array[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i]; j++)
            printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"Here's a solution that achieve the desired result:"* - No, it doesn't. Have you tried it with fewer numbers?

Comment: @klutt Actually yes, just tested with different inputs and it works, here's the output with just 2 numbers: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8wh2.png)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica when I pass in ^D as input, it stops reading: [run example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHJ0y.gif). I have always done it this way, and always worked, am I missing something?

Comment: Ok I forgot that `EOF` is different on Windows and Linux. On Windows `^Z` is `EOF`, while on Linux it's `^D`. Since the OP didn't specify it I just assumed it was Windows and so ^D is not for EOF and it works fine, but I may be wrong. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica are you running it on Windows?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica oh I'm totally dumb, I've just notice I didn't copy and paste the right update: there was a check on the number of characters read, and break if it is negative or zero. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, `if (scanf_s("%d", &value) <= 0)` is much better.  Consider `if (scanf_s("%d", &value) < 1)` as `1` is the desired result.  `0` is just one of the undesired results.  Other comments deleted.

Answer (score -2):

You need to dynamically allocate space for your data (as you do not know the size of it in advance).

Use functions - do not program in the `main` function

```
int *addtoArray(int *arr, size_t *size, int val)
{
    arr = realloc(arr, (*size + 1) * sizeof(*arr));

    if(arr)
    {
        arr[*size] = val;
        *size += 1;
    }
    return arr;
}

int *readIntegers(int *arr, FILE *fi, size_t *size, const size_t maxcount)
{
    /* addd some parameter chaeck here */
    int val;
    while(fscanf(fi, "%d", &val) == 1)
    {
        int *tmp = addtoArray(arr, size, val);
        if(tmp) arr = tmp;
        else { /* error handling*/ }
        if(*size == MAXSIZE) break;
    } 
    return arr;
}


int main(void)
{
    int *arr = 0;
    size_t size = 0;

    arr = readIntegers(arr, stdin, &size, MAXSIZE);

    printf("Elements scanned: %zu\n", size);
    free(arr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qeKPfGM3c

Comment: *"I am trying to get an indefinite input of numbers **(max 50)** "*

Comment: @klutt And ????

Comment: That means that dynamical allocation is not needed

Comment: @klutt It is hard to reply to this kind of comments ‍♂️

Comment: @0___________ That's exactly when you would use static allocation.

Comment: @0___________ you wrote "you **need** to use dynamical allocation" which is not true.

Comment: @mikyll98 your comment makes no sense at all. What exactly?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my comment. Sure, there are times when your method is the preferred solution, but it introduces extra complexity.

Comment: @0___________ The question literally says that you know what can the max array size be, so why would you use dynamically allocation? Also I find your comments quite rude and aggressive.

Comment: @mikyll98 try to convert it to the function which will be reading more than one array. How static allocation will help. You simply assume the most trivial case.

Comment: We assume the case that is specified in the question. If you said that dynamic allocation can be used to allow for arbitrary amount of numbers, that would be one thing. But right now you're saying that OP needs dynamic allocation even though there's a specified limit, which is simply not true.